# how to post on google plus, getting ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-plus

buddies i am following api-doc here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started, as in this they told to register app on `apis/console`, i registered it and got Client Id, but don't know where to use this id.

I want to post on wall (Streams) programatically, i got one example in this doc like below code

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
    .getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent,0);
```

but when i run it i am getting `ActivityNotFound Exception`, can you please tell me how can i resolve it,
If you require more info about my issue, i can share my code here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your are getting `ActivityNotFoundException`, it means you either not have such Activity or not registered that,
for now i think you don't have it. So please make sure that you have google+ application installed in you mobile phone, if not then install it first, run it, then it will the required Activity.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify one point, you cannot share automatically. The user does have control over sharing and confirms the sharing and the content.

You should [check that the user has the Google+ app installed and not disabled](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#faq-check-for-googleplus) before you launch the share intent.

```
int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this);
if (errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
  GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
}
```

[GooglePlusUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/GooglePlusUtil.html) is in the Google Play Services SDK

Comment: I can not use GooglePlusUtil.Because It says GooglePlusUtil not found.I imported Google Play Services SDK in my project.